# how to read excel in silverlight

Tags: excel, silverlight, c#-4.0

For .xls files it's working fine,But .xlsx file i am getting following error

"An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code".Let me know how to read .xlsx file.

```
OpenFileDialog oFile = new OpenFileDialog();
oFile.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
if (oFile.ShowDialog() == true)
{
  FileStream fs = oFile.File.OpenRead();

  Workbook book = Workbook.Open(fs);

  Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];

  for (int i = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; i < sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; i++)
   {
      for (int j = sheet.Cells.FirstColIndex; j < sheet.Cells.LastColIndex; j++)
        {
           this.textBox1.Text += sheet.Cells[i, j].StringValue;
           //this.textBox1.Text += ",";

         }
       this.textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Is the xlsx file significantly bigger than the xls?

Comment: compare to xls file, .xlsx memory size is less.But I am getting memory exception.How com???.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try flushing your filestream in the loop, then closing the file stream when you're done with it:

```
OpenFileDialog oFile = new OpenFileDialog();
oFile.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
if (oFile.ShowDialog() == true) {
    FileStream fs = oFile.File.OpenRead();

    Workbook book = Workbook.Open(fs);

    Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets(0);

    for (int i = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; i <= sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = sheet.Cells.FirstColIndex; j <= sheet.Cells.LastColIndex - 1; j++) {
            //this.textBox1.Text += ",";
            this.textBox1.Text += sheet.Cells(i, j).StringValue;
            fs.Flush();
        }
        this.textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;

   }
fs.Close();
 }
```

Also here: `oFile.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";` you are just filtering to xls files

Comment: how we can use workbook in a silver-light application bcos i am unable to use it.